# Templating database queries in Electron js

Tags: javascript, mysql, twig, electron, pug

I'm using ElectronJS to build a simple CRUD that connects to an online database (I'm using MySQL to retrieve data from the database). I can log it to the console but I want to display it on my window. I have looked for template options but so far nothing's useful, how do I display the data I retrieve from the MySQL database to my window?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are retrieving the data in the `main` process , and your window is running on the `renderer` process so first you have to pass that data to the `renderer` process using electron `IPC` communication feature then you will be able to display that data to the Window i.e. `renderer` process.

Comment: so i query the data in my renderer process then pass it to the html page ?